# Haskell parallelisation and strict evaluation in thread..?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I was trying to find prime numbers from a given list of numbers.
So far I have piece of code that works, but if I uncomment some lines and comment some others, I don't see any difference in speed.
I am almost sure that I have to force evaluation in separate thread, as I think I start thread but code is not evaluated there due to laziness. But I couldn't find a way to force that evaluation. I was working based on examples [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html). So I made functions `parMap` and `strMap` which are parallel map and strict [parallel] map. In `parMap` there are 2 lines commented, so if you uncomment them, and comment out other 4 lines that are currently not commented, well, you cant notice any difference in speed, although it should be non-parallel and slower then. I also ignore program args for now in `main` function.

So basically my question is - is it possible to achieve, that for each number in list that is given to `parMap`, a new thread is spawned and so everything works faster?

here goes the code:

```
module W7T5
(
  main
) where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Parallel (par, pseq)
import System.Environment

main = do
  args' <- getArgs
  let
--    args = map (\x -> read x :: Int) args'
    args = [2000000..2000200]
    tfPrime = parMap isPrime' args
--    tfPrime = strMap isPrime' args
    argsNtf = zip args tfPrime
    primes' = filter (\(num, tfPrime) -> tfPrime) argsNtf
    primes = map fst primes'
  putStrLn ("Init list: " ++ show args)
  putStrLn ("Primes   : " ++ show primes)

-- Map in parallel
parMap :: NFData a => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
parMap _ [] =
  []
--parMap f (x:xs) = -- sadly without any parallelisation it's not slower
--  (f x) :parMap f xs
parMap f (x:xs) =
  par r (r:parMap f xs)
  where
    r = f x

-- Map in parallel strictly
strMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
strMap f xs =
  forceList xs `seq` map f xs

forceList :: [a] -> ()
forceList (x:xs) =
  xs `pseq` forceList xs
forceList _ =
  ()

isPrime' :: Int -> Bool
isPrime' 0 = True
isPrime' 1 = True
isPrime' 2 = True
isPrime' num =
  all (/=0) [mod num x | x <- [2..(num-1)]]
```

You can run the program with

```
runhaskell W7T5.hs 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Are you sure you use more than 1 thread? ghc has an option "-threaded" for compiling with more than 1 thread. The compiled program takes then the option "+RTS -N2" to run it on two cores. Not sure how about doing this with runhaskell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For speed (which is the point of parallelism), Haskell programs should be compiled (with `ghc`) rather than interpreted (with `runghc`). I don't know how to actually use `runghc` for multithreading, if that's possible at all.

```
ghc W7T5 -threaded -with-rts -N2
./W7T5
```

---

The `parMap` implementation isn't correct: the computation `(r : parMap f xs)` returns immediately and just thunks the tail, which will only be sparked when it will be demanded (but by then it will be too late). The one below sparks both the head and tail before consing them, so by the time the caller see the constructor, the rest of the list is being evaluated in the background.

```
parMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
parMap f [] = []
parMap f (x : xs) = rs `par` r `par` (r : rs)
  where
    r = f x
    rs = parMap f xs
```

---

When you compile your program, you'll probably not see the same buffering behavior as with an interpreter, because executables use line buffering by default. Buffering can be turned off using `System.IO.hSetBuffering`

```
import System.IO

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  ...
```

Comment: Is there any thorough guide on how to compile Haskell? What arguments to use and what they do?

Comment: [Here's a very short introduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_5_steps) to get started.

For all options, check out the [GHC User's guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/index.html).